# How to cover also the UIStatusBar with UIView when i cover all the screen with the UIView? (iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screen, uistatusbar

How to cover also the UIStatusBar with UIView when i cover all the screen with the UIView?

Answer (score 6):

I was battling how to do this for a long time too!  Finally figured it out :)  The key is to set the windowLevel of your new window to really high so it lives on top of all the other windows/views/statusbar etc:

```
UIWindow *keyWin = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIWindow *hudWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, keyWin.frame.size.width, keyWin.frame.size.height)];
hudWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
hudWindow.alpha = 0.60;
[hudWindow setWindowLevel:10000.0f];
[hudWindow setHidden:NO];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I dug a little further, and found that the windowLevel property has some constants that represent certain levels:

const UIWindowLevel UIWindowLevelNormal;
const UIWindowLevel UIWindowLevelAlert;
const UIWindowLevel UIWindowLevelStatusBar;

I found UIWindowLevelStatusBar does the trick.

Comment: Note that if you call `keyWindow` when the app launches, it is possible for the value to be nil. Better to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to get the window frame.

Comment: This does not work when the keyboard is on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is hide the status bar with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]
```

and show it again when you need it.

You can basically `removeFromSuperview` any time you want to remove the view.

Comment: That API is deprecated. The replacement is `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a `UIAlertView`-like effect, I don't think you can do this. You might file a feature enhancement request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: this is doable, just use a UIWindow.  I added an answer with the method i employ.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, but I made these two changes. Adding 1.0 to UIWindowLevel still hides the status bar, and I have no idea why.

```
self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+2.0f;

self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Setting the Statusbar userInteractionEnabled property to NO will ensure that your scroll views will scroll to top when someone taps on this statusbar.